# Using two functions to plot one function

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, functions, code-review, missing

I want to plot the following function, where `Uin` is the variable (that has to be on the x-axis):

```
y[Uin]:=2*fin*(2*T*Ud - ((Ud)/(fin)) + ((Uin*Sin[2*Pi*fin*T])/(2*Pi*fin)) + 
   c*Rb*(2*Ud - Uin)*(Exp[-((T)/(c*Rb))] - 1))
```

Now `Ud`,`fin`,`Rb` and `c`are constants, for example

```
Ud = 0.7, fin = 50, Rb = 10 , c = 150*10^(-6)
```

But to find `T` I need to solve:

```
FindRoot[
 Abs[Uin*Sin[2*Pi*fin*T - (Pi/2)]] - 2*Ud == (Uin - 2*Ud)*Exp[-T/(c*Rb)]
 , {T, 1/(4*fin), 1/(2*fin)}
 , WorkingPrecision -> 20
 ]
```

Now how can I plot the function `y[Uin]` while varying `Uin`?

---

**My work**, I programmed:

```
Ud = 0.7; fin = 50; Rb = 10; c = 150*10^(-6);
y[Uin_] = 
  2*fin*(2*T*Ud - ((Ud)/(fin)) + ((Uin*Sin[2*Pi*fin*T])/(2*Pi*fin)) + 
     c*Rb*(2*Ud - Uin)*(Exp[-((T)/(c*Rb))] - 1));
Teqn[Uin_] = 
  Abs[Uin*Sin[2*Pi*fin*T - (Pi/2)]] - 2*Ud == (Uin - 2*Ud)*
    Exp[-T/(c*Rb)];
Tsol[Uin_?NumericQ] := 
 FindRoot[Teqn[Uin], {T, 1/(4*fin), 1/(2*fin)}]; ListPlot[
 Table[{Uin, y[Uin] /. Tsol[Uin]}, {Uin, 0, 10, 0.001}]]
```

But that produces a not correct result (it gives that `y[Uin]` stays $1.5$ for all `Uin` but that can not be possible).

Comment: You are providing two values for the `T`specification in `FindRoot`. Those are used as the first and second values in the iteration, in order to avoid the internal use of derivatives. Is that what you intended? Perhaps a better starting value and a search interval for `T` would work better to avoid the warnings returned by `FindRoot` in your current code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FindRoot evidently is not finding all the values.  You can set up your tables before using FindRoot.

```
Ud = 0.7; fin = 50; Rb = 10; c = 150*10^(-6);

Teqn[Uin_] = 
 Abs[Uin*Sin[2*Pi*fin*T - (Pi/2)]] - 2*Ud == (Uin - 2*Ud)*
   Exp[-T/(c*Rb)]
```

Table of  Uin values

```
TUin = Table[Uin, {Uin, 0, 10, 0.001}];
```

Get a table of T with FindRoot.

```
Ttab = Table[
   T /. FindRoot[Teqn[TUin[[i]]], {T, 1/(4*fin), 1/(2*fin)}], {i, 
    Length[TUin]}];
```

We get some convergence warnings because for some values of Uin, there are no roots for T in the specified range.
Define y.

```
y := 2*fin*(2*Ttab[[i]]*
     Ud - ((Ud)/(fin)) + ((TUin[[i]]*Sin[2*Pi*fin*Ttab[[i]]])/(2*Pi*
        fin)) + c*
     Rb*(2*Ud - TUin[[i]])*(Exp[-((Ttab[[i]])/(c*Rb))] - 1));

ListPlot[Table[{TUin[[i]], y}, {i, Length[Ttab]}], PlotJoined -> True]
```

[image]

The jumpy part of the early curve is due to the failure to find roots in the specified interval.  You might need to relook at your data for those values.

Comment: "there are no roots for T *in the specified range*": if you mean the three-value syntax for the `FindRoot` variable, note that it provides two *starting points*, not a range; you must provide *four* values for that.